# Как уменьшить длину вектора, не меняя его направления в 2D-пространстве?

Tags: математика, геометрия, вектор

Вопрос о векторе, представленным точкой начала `(0, 0)` и точкой конца `(5, 4)`.

Как уменьшить модуль такого вектора, не меняя его направления в двумерном пространстве?

Comment: @NameX, Это вопрос на форум [Математика](http://math.hashcode.ru/).

Comment: @NameX, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @zenith Я не по учебе. Я пишу игрушку и там требуется что бы враги окружили игрока. Но уже сам(вроде) додумался. Сейчас пробую.)

Comment: Ужас-то какой. Это довузовская программа :(  
ИМХО, сначала подучи математику, потом пиши игры.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он несёт в себе просьбу автора выполнить работу за него и не имеет никакой ценности для сообщества. Пожалуйста, ознакомиться с советами о том, [как задать хороший вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). - [Из очереди проверок](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/150274)

Comment: 3й признак подобия треугольников, геометрия 8 класс.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cначала находим координаты вектора:

```
v = (5 - 0; 4 - 0) = (5; 4).
```

Затем находим вектор v_0 единичной длины,  по направлению совпадающий с исходным:

```
v_0 = v / |v| = v / sqrt(5 ^ 2 + 4 ^ 2) = (5; 4) / sqrt(41)
```

Пусть мы хотим получить вектор длины d. Для этого просто умножаем v_0 на d:

```
v_0 * d = (5 * d /  sqrt(41); 4 * d / sqrt(41))
```

Answer (score 6):

Допустим `k` - коэффициент уменьшения. Тогда новый вектор с координатами х2 и у2 будет:

```
х2 = х1 / k
у2 = у1 / k
```